# Axios request stuck on pending

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a vue app utlizing axios for requests and am using a module/service architecture.

In my service I have the following:

```
clientsGrouped: async function(startDate, endDate, group_by="", compare="") {
    return axios.get(
      `/dashboards/clients/simple_split.json?start_date=${ startDate }&end_date=${ endDate }&location_ids=${ store.getters.selectedLocations }&compare=${compare}&group_by=${group_by}`
    )
}
```

and it is called from within my module as:

```
async fetchGroupedClients({ commit }, data) {
    let groupBy = data.group_by
    let compare = data.compare
    let startDate = data.startDate
    let endDate = data.endDate

    console.log(data, groupBy, compare)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ClientsService.clientsGrouped(startDate, endDate, groupBy, compare).then(response => {
        console.log(response);

        let data = {
          series: _.values(response.data),
          labels: _.keys(response.data)
        }

        resolve(data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error)
      })
    })
  },
```

Is there a reason this would never terminate?  Am I calling something incorrectly?  My chrome debugger just shows the request stuck at pending.

Comment: If it is pending on the network tab, it means it's just pending. Have you tried loading an easy API you would know by facts it will give a response?

Comment: It's just strange.  It seems to happen if there's an error in my server, but the error isn't sent or something.  I don't really understand the root of the issue.